# Flask-WhooshAlchemy returning empty

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, whoosh

I'm developing a Python-Flask application and I want to implement a **Full Text Search** which is pretty simple with Flask-WhooshAlchemy, atleast I thought so. This is driving me crazy because , apparently, there isnt any reason why this isnt working. 
This is my **models.py**

```
from project import app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from werkzeug import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
import flask_whooshalchemy as wa
import datetime
import flask_whooshalchemyplus

enable_search = True


db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __searchable__ = ['firstname']
    uid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    pwdhash = db.Column(db.String(150))
    urole = db.Column(db.String(80))

    # -----login requirements-----
    def is_active(self):
        # all users are active
        return True

    def get_id(self):
        # returns the user e-mail. not sure who calls this
        return self.email

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        # False as we do not support annonymity
        return False

    def get_urole(self):
        return self.urole

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, email, password, urole):
        self.firstname = firstname.title()
        self.lastname = lastname.title()
        self.email = email.lower()
        self.set_password(password)
        self.urole = urole

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.pwdhash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.pwdhash, password)


proposal_politician_association = db.Table('politicsproposals',
                                           db.Column('idPolitician', db.Integer,
                                                     db.ForeignKey('politics.idPolitician')),
                                           db.Column('idProposal', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('proposals.idProposal')))

wa.whoosh_index(app, User)
class Politic(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'politics'
    __searchable__ = ['publicName', 'completeName']

    idPolitician = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    publicName = db.Column(db.String(150))
    completeName = db.Column(db.String(300))
    startDate = db.Column(db.Date, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    endDate = db.Column(db.Date, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    flag = db.relationship('Flag', backref='politics', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self, publicName, completeName, startDate, endDate):
        self.publicName = publicName.title()
        self.completeName = completeName.title()
        self.startDate = startDate.title()
        self.endDate = endDate.title()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Politic hello %r>' % (self.completeName)


wa.whoosh_index(app,Politic)
```

I ran it automatically and manually.

```
>>> wa.whoosh_index(app, Politic)
>>> Out[69]: FileIndex(FileStorage('whoosh/Politic'), 'MAIN')
```

Still nothing appeared when Running this query:

```
>>> Politic.query.whoosh_search('Pedro').all()
>>> Out[56]: []
```

I was intrigued so I checked my whoosh_index to see details:

```
>>> ix = open_dir('whoosh_index/Politic')
>>> ix.schema
>>> Out[73]: <Schema: ['completeName', 'idPolitician', 'publicName']>
```

and deeper:

```
>>> from whoosh.query import Every
>>> results = ix.searcher().search(Every('content'))
```

And the result is again, empty..

```
>>> for result in results:
>>>    print result['idPoltician']
```

I don't know where I'm messing or what is so hard about this. 
Did anyone had this problem before and figured out what was the problem?

Any help would be huge. I'm stucked here big time

Comment: No error and empty answer, no traceback no soup.  don't publish any script before testing all variations. Some time need using foolish answer. Like this. "I search but not found !", "can't execute this code ", "I try building but not serving !". My opinion "can't use an service as module" i can't imagine which script handled your threats.

Comment: Was the data in your table inserted before or after you created the whoosh index?

Comment: @dsgdfg That's what is called Reductio ad absurdum. But it's okay. I think I posted a decent and self explanatory question, with the original problem(whoosh_index returning empty) and my debug which resulted on those steps.

Comment: @Miguel Before I created the whooh_index

Comment: Well, there you go. Recreate your database now that you have the index, and hopefully everything will work.

Comment: What do you mean? Insert new data and see if it works?

Comment: Test your SQL script on idle with default user(not root or administrator). You haven't any problem if got any output(@Miguel comments). Need create a SQL injector/manager script(python) before broadcasting of service(handled error, states, condutions). If  `A` and `B` is different service, you never know which raised an error or non-valid data ! `Unittest` is very important point on creating a service. Basic application need `Recovery`, `Test`, `Backup`, `Demo`, `Thread Manager`, `Hardware Tester`, `Service Checker`,`Logger` etc. parts. **Your code don't provide any traceback !**

Comment: @Perseverance yes, the data that was inserted before the full-text index existed is not indexed. Any data that you insert from now on should be indexed and searchable.